# Why can't I initialize a int* with the address of a const int

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

This is what I have:

```
const int x = 10;
int *ptr = &x; //error: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const int *' to 'int *'
```

I know `x` can't be modified after initializing and I know how to fix this compilation problem, but why can't I use a pointer (in this case `ptr`) to point to `x`?

Although it is a `const int`, I don't understand the reason behind of why can't I point to it, as I can still use `*ptr` to represent `x`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `ptr` is of type `int*`, i.e. it points to a non-const `int`. This allows you to modify `ptr` using `*ptr`. To prevent the `const` variable from being modified, the compiler prevents the initial assignment to a non-const pointer.

Making `ptr` point to a `const int` will naturally fix the problem: `const int* ptr = &x;`

Comment: Because I am pointing to a const int, so even if I point to x, it is useless because I cannot modify the value using *?

Comment: @PzrrL yes, because `x` is a `const int`

Comment: @Rekete1111 Although it is a `const int`, I don't understand the reason behind of why can't I point to it, as I can still use `*ptr` to represent `x`, right?

Comment: @PzrrL you can point to it (`const int* ptr = &x;`), you just have to define `ptr` as a pointer to a **`const int`**, not just an `int`

Comment: @PzrrL: If someone has an `int* ptr`, and does `*ptr = 99` (after verifying that `ptr` is not null), then it is perfectly reasonable for them to expect `*ptr == 99`. But if `ptr` is storing the address of a const value, then that won't work. So the language doesn't even allow you to do that (at least, not without a cast).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Can I understand that in this way? Because after `ptr` pointing to a `const int`, when I use `*ptr` to do assignment, it is illegal. To avoid this, the language don't even allow me to do use `int *ptr` to point to a `const int`?

Comment: @PzrrL: That is correct.